# How to create an ASP.NET Core class library

Tags: asp.net-core, class-library

I want to use Visual Studio tooling around razor pages, components, views etc. for a project I am working on.

The scenario is the following: I want to have one main web application which is pluggable, so there shall be no direct reference to the plugins (which are class libraries).

- class library should allow for razor pages etc
- class library should allow for displaying controllers (that one already works)

What I did so far was changing the project file and changing the SDK to `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web`

You can reproduce this issue with this [GitHub](https://github.com/taori/Sandbox.git)-link.

However the project I have changed now has "connected services" and `launchSettings.json`.

Is that a behavior I can ignore or will the project have side effects with the change I made?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for (and what the switch to the SDK did) is a Razor Class Library, or RCL for short. It looks like you might have started with an ASP.NET Core site, which would explain the presence of `launchSettings.json`. An RCL is similar to an ASP.NET Core site in that you can include most of the same things: controllers, views, Razor pages, view components, tag helpers, static files, etc. However, notably, you will not have a `Program.cs`, `Startup.cs`, `launchSettings.json`, or any configuration files like `appsettings.json`. This is because, at the end of the day, it's just a library, and not something that runs on its own or stands on its own. You can make use of standard abstractions like `IConfiguration`/`IOptions`, `ILogger`, etc., but the actual implementation of these will come from your app, not the library. You should consult the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) for more information.